# Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have developed a desktop software using Visual Studio 2019 and Crystal Report, and I have installed Crystal Report SP32

And at client PC which is 64 bit, I have installed Crystal Report Engine SP32 - this file --- CR13SP32Redist64_0-80007712

But when run App on client PC this error appear:

```
The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. --->

 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException:

An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime.

Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient,

or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly.

 Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the 
correct version

of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not related to any code, it is Crystal Report problem